# Linux cache fails when installing library for R - gdal

Tags: r, linux, rgdal

I run R Studio Server in a Redhat Linux virtual machine. I am trying to install the rgdal library in R with no success, and after reading many posts here on SO the proper fix to this issue is to install the following software on Linux:

```
yum install gdal-devel
yum install proj-devel
yum install proj-nad
yum install proj-epsg
```

but when I tried to do this I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from Spacewalk server.
https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#35 - "Encountered end of file"
Trying other mirror.
addons7                                                                                                     | 1.1 kB  00:00:00
base_7.4                                                                                                    | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
cliente7                                                                                                    |  871 B  00:00:00
epel_7                                                                                                      | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
latest7                                                                                                     | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
mysql7_57                                                                                                   |  871 B  00:00:00
remi7_55                                                                                                    |  871 B  00:00:00
remi7_56                                                                                                    |  871 B  00:00:00
remi7_safe                                                                                                  |  871 B  00:00:00
softwarecollections7                                                                                        | 1.1 kB  00:00:00


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

failed to retrieve repodata/primary.xml.gz from softwarecollections7
error was [Errno 14] curl#18 - "transfer closed with 954471 bytes remaining to read"
```

How can I resolve this? For instance, there is a suggestion of disabling the repo, but I don't know what I have to put in the "..." portion.

Comment: Tips for posting on Stack Overflow that will improve your experience here: (1) install and use an English spell-checker; (2) observe the normal rules of case for English; (3) keep your posts to technical writing, and refrain from using the site in the same way as social media or a chatroom.

Comment: Standard advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._